# Implicit cast of null pointer to bool

Tags: c++, pointers

Suppose I have `Foo* foo = nullptr;`

If I'm checking whether or not `foo` is `nullptr`, am I permitted to write

```
if (!foo)
```

or should I write

```
if (foo == nullptr)
```

Comment: Both are fine and is more a coding style issue.  Follow the style of existing code or if it's your code use which ever is clearer to you.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

See this standard reference (bold emphasis mine):

**C++11 §4.12 Boolean conversions**

> A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or pointer to
>   member type can be converted to a prvalue of type bool. **A zero value,
>   null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted to
>   false; any other value is converted to true.** A prvalue of type
>   std::nullptr_t can be converted to a prvalue of type bool; the
>   resulting value is false.

The middle sentence is relevant: it is telling you that the null pointer value (`foo = nullptr`) *can* be implicitly cast to `false` which itself has type `bool`. Therefore `if (!foo)` is well-defined.

Answer (score 3):

In C++, the null pointer is defined as

> A null pointer constant is an integral constant expression (5.19)
>   rvalue of integer type that evaluates to zero.

That's why,

```
Foo* foo = nullptr;
```

is like:

```
Foo* foo = 0;
```

Moreover, in C++ zero(0) count as boolean `false`. So your statement `if (foo == nullptr)` is valid and same as `if (!foo)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!foo)
```

This works fine.

```
if (foo == nullptr)
```

This would look more clear to someone reading your code.