# Check pointer's nullability: !pointer or pointer == nullptr?

Tags: c++, pointers

Suppose I have a pointer: `int *pointer`.

If I want to test its nullability, should I do it with:

```
bool nullability = !pointer;
```

Or with:

```
bool nullability = (pointer == nullptr);
```

Are both expressions equivalent?
If not, why and what are the side effects?

Comment: See here for some ideas http://stackoverflow.com/a/17774781/133203

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both are equivaluent because `nullptr` is guaranteed to be converted to `false` when converted to a boolean.

From N4296:

> **4.12 Boolean conversions**
>   <sup>1</sup> A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or pointer to member type can be
>   converted to a prvalue of type bool. A zero value, null pointer value,
>   or null member pointer value is converted to false; any other value is
>   converted to true. For direct-initialization (8.5), a prvalue of type
>   std::nullptr_t can be converted to a prvalue of type bool; the
>   resulting value is false.

Answer (score 2):

According the standard and this answers ([Implicit cast of null pointer to bool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33474487/implicit-cast-of-null-pointer-to-bool)) the two syntax have the same behavior