# Dereferencing head of empty linked list for next node

Tags: c++, singly-linked-list, dereference

I was trying to implement linked list in C++, when this idea struck my mind. With standard node definition as

```
class node {
public:
    int data;
    node *next;
};
```

I created an empty list `node *head;` then tried this

```
if(head->next == nullptr)
    cout<<"Stores nullptr";
if(! head->next)
    cout<<"Returns bool values";
```

But there is no output, so what is stored inside `head->next` ?

Comment: I can't see you do initialization of `next` anywhere, so it will contain a random value. Also the conditions in your `if` statements are equivalent.

Comment: *I created an empty list* `node *head;` - no, you've created an uninitialized pointer to node class instance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implicit cast of null pointer to bool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33474487/implicit-cast-of-null-pointer-to-bool)

Comment: To everyone, don't you think c++ automatically does these initializations and create default constructor, I was just exploiting that fact. Now, my question was just what is stored inside `head->next` if head is nullptr(by default)?

Comment: @Snigdh _"don't you think c++ automatically does these initializations"_ No we don't think so. We **know** that it doesn't.

Comment: It is atleast mentioned in my book and my compiler does this also.

Comment: @Snigdh Your book is wrong then or you confused something.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Ok, so where can I read about this can you provide any reference please.

Comment: @Snigdh [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910832/why-arent-pointers-initialized-with-null-by-default) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26142100/c-default-constructor-does-not-initialize-pointer-to-nullptr)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should create some space/allocate memory for the node class in main.

Note that 
`node *head;` is only a declaration not a definition. For further details have a look at [What is the difference between a definition and a declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration).

1. You allocate space for the object
2. Initialize its values, to be more elegant define a constructor method

```
    node *head = new node;
    head->next = nullptr;
    head->data=0;
```

I would still consider this as a duplicate of [Linked lists in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14544539/linked-lists-in-c)

Comment: If you consider duplicates just flag the question as such, instead of writing an answer.

Answer (score -1):

If you declare `node *head;`, head is an uninitialized pointer that contains a random address. Dereferencing it is *Undefined Behavior*?

You need to a) initialize head: `node *head = nullptr;`, and b) test for that condition: `if (head == nullptr) { head = new node; node->head = nullptr; ...`